# How do I make a calendar table > td a selectable form element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I am making an events booking form and I need the user to be able to click in a table cell on the calendar to select their start date.

Sadly I have limited knowledge of Javascript, having thrown all my weight behind PHP for the past couple of months.

So as I understand it I need to perform some sort of ajax operation to 'GET' the date (e.g. 2016/9/16) and send it off as POST data along with the rest of my form data. I am enrolled in an AJAX course on udemy thankfully.

**What I have so far.**

Here is my form

[image]

The calendars are simple tables, each day is a link to a specific page with data in the url like `example/2016/5/4`.

Here is how I am generating my calendars...

```
{table_open}<table id="tt-calendar">{/table_open}

                    {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

                        {heading_previous_cell}
                            <th class="text-center">

                            </th>
                        {/heading_previous_cell}

                        {heading_title_cell}
                            <th class="text-center" colspan="{colspan}">
                                <h4>
                                    {heading}
                                </h4>
                            </th>
                        {/heading_title_cell}

                        {heading_next_cell}
                            <th class="text-center">

                            </th>
                        {/heading_next_cell}

                    {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}
                    {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}

                        {week_day_cell}
                            <td>
                                <strong>
                                    {week_day}
                                </strong>
                            </td>
                        {/week_day_cell}

                    {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}
                    {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}

                        {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

                        {cal_cell_start_today}<td id="tt-calendar-today">{/cal_cell_start_today}

                        {cal_cell_start_other}<td id="tt-calendar-test">{/cal_cell_start_other}

                        {cal_cell_content}
                            <a id="tt-calendar-event" href="' .  base_url() . 'schedule/today/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/{day}/' . $student_id . '">
                                {day}
                            </a>
                        {/cal_cell_content}

                        {cal_cell_content_today}
                            <a href="' .  base_url() . 'schedule/today/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/{day}/' . $student_id . '">
                                {day}
                            </a>
                        {/cal_cell_content_today}

                        {cal_cell_no_content}
                            <a href="' .  base_url() . 'schedule/today/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/{day}/' . $student_id . '">
                                {day}
                            </a>
                        {/cal_cell_no_content}

                        {cal_cell_no_content_today}
                            <a href="' .  base_url() . 'schedule/today/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/{day}/' . $student_id . '">
                                {day}
                            </a>
                        {/cal_cell_no_content_today}

                        {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

                        {cal_cell_other}{day}{/cal_cel_other}

                        {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}

                        {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}

                        {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}

                    {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

                {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
```

So... how do I make a calendar 'td' element a selectable 'form' element that is able to pass its POST data on along with the rest of the form post data?
Links to extra articles/tutorials would be appreciated...

Comment: You’re thinking to complicated. Don’t try to “make” the table cells into anything else, but just have a hidden field for the date in your form already to begin with. Then on click on a table cell, you fill that hidden field with the corresponding value. (Or make it a date input field in the first place. and let the datepicker handle the rest. Needs a polyfil for the datepicker in browsers that don’t support it yet.)

Comment: Hey, that is freaking brilliant. What a great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a tutorial you might use

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-the-calendar-library--net-9570

If that doesnt work, use this one

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMsEAtXtE2g